# Does the LXX of Proverbs 1:7 have influence on the use of εὐσέβεια in the NT?

Tags: greek, new-testament, septuagint, proverbs, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible

Is there any New Testament text wherin an influence of this LXX expanded translation is of interpretive importance in the NT (esp. with regard to εὐσέβεια)?

**Edit (question clarification):**
I find this expansion of the LXX interesting; and the use of the LXX in the NT to be very helpful for biblical-historical interpretation. As a point of entry, Titus 1:1 is one place where Paul uses εὐσέβεια, but there is no immediate indication the original readers would hear a clear reminder of Proverbs 1:7. I am wanting to learn, from informed discussion here, as to whether any of the NT usages of εὐσέβεια (or another phrase from the GK of Pr.1:7) would directly tie piety("godliness") or another NT wisdom motif more or less directly to the beginning of wisdom in LXX Proverbs 1:7.

[ Note: Nestle-Aland 27th ed. GNT list of NT citations of OT does not have any reference to Pr.1:7; but this is not an exhaustive list. G.K. Beale and D.A. Carson's *Commentary on the New Testament Use of the Old Testament* indicates there may be some references.]

**The Hebrew**

(Prov 1:7 [**WLC**])[snippets from theWord.net application]

יִרְאַת יְהוָה רֵאשִׁית דָּעַת חָכְמָה וּמוּסָר אֱוִילִים בָּֽזוּ׃ פ

**Translated** [mine] as:
The fear of the Lord is the beginning of knowledge,
wisdom and instuction fools despise;

**Greek (expanded) Translation**

(Prov 1:7 [**LXX**])
ἀρχὴ σοφίας φόβος θεοῦ σύνεσις δὲ ἀγαθὴ πᾶσι τοῖς ποιοῦσιν αὐτήν εὐσέβεια δὲ εἰς θεὸν ἀρχὴ αἰσθήσεως σοφίαν δὲ καὶ παιδείαν ἀσεβεῖς ἐξουθενήσουσιν

**Translated** [from www.ecmarsh.com/lxx/Proverbs/index.htm]:
7 The fear of the Lord is the beginning of wisdom; and there is good understanding to all that practise it: and piety toward God is the beginning of discernment; but the ungodly will set at nought wisdom and instruction.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics. This is an interesting question, but I suspect there's a question behind this question. Would you mind sharing a bit more about the motivation behind asking this question? Perhaps then we can focus answers to that end and be able to answer your actual question.

Comment: Thank you. Question has been edited with clarification, in response to swasheck.

Comment: Fabulous. This went from interesting to awesome. James, Jude, and Hebrews should be good starting points.

Comment: What words/phrases from Pr.1:7 in the Greek of James, Jude and Hebrews do you mean to indicate reference for "starting points"? For example, I find "Euseb" forms to be lacking in those books.

Comment: I don't know yet but those authors would seem to have the most contact with proverbs. In fact, James is often categorized as NT wisdom literature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**INDICATIONS OF LXX PROVERBS 1:7 IN GREEK NEW TESTAMENT(?)**

**Conlusion:**

There are indications (reasons) to believe the LXX of Proverbs 1:7 has an canonical-theological influence, but the specific evidence of a references to this verse in the Gk. New Testament appears to be indeterminate. *Nevertheless, we ourselves, may be reminded, wherever we read `εὐσέβεια` in the New Testament, of the Holy God, toward which our lives must be directed, in the grace of Christ.*

**Tools Used:**

- index to Beale and Carson (eds.) *Commentary on the New Testament use of the Old Testament*;
- theWord.net Bible software (with Rahlf's LXX, Westminster Leningrad Codex, Delitzsch's Hebrew New Testament, SBLGNT Greek Text, NET Bible);
- Waltke's NICOT Commentary on Proverbs 1-15;
- s.v. εὐσέβεια in *Exegetical Dictionary of the New Testament* (abbr. EDNT, Balz & Schneider, eds., pub. by Eerdmans);

[Am assuming that these easily found resources do not need full bibliographical info]

**LXX Proverbs 1:7:**
`ἀρχὴ σοφίας φόβος θεοῦ σύνεσις δὲ ἀγαθὴ πᾶσι τοῖς ποιοῦσιν αὐτήν εὐσέβεια δὲ εἰς θεὸν ἀρχὴ αἰσθήσεως σοφίαν δὲ καὶ παιδείαν ἀσεβεῖς ἐξουθενήσουσιν` - *"The fear of the Lord is the beginning of wisdom; and there is good understanding to all that practise it: and piety toward God is the beginning of discernment; but the ungodly will set at nought wisdom and instruction."*  [from www.ecmarsh.com/lxx/Proverbs/index.htm]

**Closest Phrases:**

`φόβῳ τοῦ Κυρίου` in Acts 9:31 (*"The church ... was strengthened ... living in fear of the Lord" *).

`ἐν πάσῃ σοφίᾳ καὶ συνέσει πνευματικῇ` in Col.1:9 (*"Asking God to fill you...with knowledge..in all spiritual wisdom and understanding"*)

`εὐσεβὴς καὶ φοβούμενος τὸν θεὸν` in Acts 10:2 (*"He was a pious and God-fearing man"*)

`παιδεύουσα ἡμᾶς, ἵνα ἀρνησάμενοι τὴν ἀσέβειαν ... καὶ εὐσεβῶς ζήσωμεν...` in Titus 2:12 ("Training us to reject ungodliness...and live lives of godliness"*)

**Significant Word/Concept:**

`εὐσέβεια` - in connection with the concept of the "fear of the Lord" (evidence of which may be Acts 10:2 above) . [Philip H. Towner asserts this "godliness" - "fear of the Lord" conceptual connection in his commentary on 2 Tim 2:19 (in Beale & Carson (cited above), p.903)]

**For Improvement of this answer:**

- Textual Variants could be explored.
- Extrabiblical texts (i.e., the Greek of some early church texts) could be interesting).
- Improved search and combinatined search techniques on lemmas/morphemes/sytactical nuances.
- Further research in commentaries and journals.